# Why are there 4 spaces before asking for another input by cin.read()?

Tags: java, inputstream

When I remove the 'ln' from 'System.out.println', cin.read() ask me for input in the next line but when I put back the 'ln' there is 4 spaces before it asks me another input, why?

```
 InputStreamReader cin = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

 char c;
 do {
    c = (char) cin.read();
    System.out.println(c);
    } while(c != 'q');
```

Comment: it read and print all the input include the \n (or your OS line.separator),
[read() will not block while there are more chars to be read]
if you want to see it more clear use 

c = (char) cin.read();
System.out.print((int)c+"-");
System.out.print(c+" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputStreamReader`  is not designed to read chars from the client input that is `System.in`.   It is a bridge from bytes to chars.
`InputStreamReader.read()` will indeed read byte by byte including those representing the line separator produced by the enter type.
So when you enter in the std input for example `x` and then you click `Enter`, according to your OS 2 or 3 bytes are read and decoded into chars.
`x` `\r` `\n` for Windows OS based and `x` `\n` for Unix OS based.
As you notice 4 break lines (3 for the read bytes + 1 automatically added after you type the enter touch) you are very probably on Windows.

To read text from the std input, `Scanner` is more suitable such as :

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

String word;
do {
    word = cin.next();
    System.out.println(word);
} while (!word.equals("q"));
```

Comment: I followed what Sarel Foyerlicht suggested and I saw the line feed and carriage return in the console, so are you saying that my variable c store 3 character and that will make my System.out.println method called 3 times even though I called System.out.println method once in my do while loop?

Comment: The `c` variable stores indeed 3 different values (one for each iteration) and so as you have 3 iterations , `println()` is invoked 3 times.